# best way too manage the size of a growing images folder

Tags: php, image, directory

**I have a contactform with a canvas where people can draw something.
After submission the file get's created in a folder and a mail is send to me with the embedded
image using phpmailer.**

*I am planning to keep the names of the files in the database with a timestamp and delete the ones that are too old, but I can see the size of the folder can get pretty big.
I am on a shared host and I am already close to my datalimit.
Because the emails need a reference to the image, the image needs to be created otherwise the mail-size get's to big.
Once I have read the email, I don't need the image anymore. I don't know yet if I want to save it for the user.*

What are my possible options.
A third party is also good, if it's a relativly easy thing to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could use the [imgur](http://api.imgur.com/) api for example. There you can save the delete hash in the database too and if not needed you can delete pictures from imgur.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you store the images as binary data inside a database? Doesn't waste any of your disk hard space, and makes the images more safe and safer if they do contain a virus.

Comment: I have thought about that, but I thought it would compromise sending the email with the embedded image. Can you explain how it would work with the email..

Comment: well, you could always create a PHP system which retrieves the images from the database, and use `<img src="thephpfile.php?id=foo" />` or something similar to that. Check online or other places for ways to retrieve data stored using binary in the database.

Comment: for some reason, getting it in and out the blob field is not working.

Comment: After researching all the possible ways where it could go wrong, I just quit, because I couldn't get any work done. Maybe, it was a utf8 bom or a PDO bug in version 5.3 or encoding problems with the transportation of the data. The filesystem seems a lot simpeler now.